# Adding Views programatically through array adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

I am displaying a listview using an arrayadapter. for each listitem i inflate the same xml file.i am able to display the listview fine.but now i have another requirement. i want to add some more view programatically to the same xml file that i am inflating for each list item. but when i try to do that i am not getting any error. but somehow the view i added programatically is not showing up...can anyone please help me. below is the code for the xml layout and for the arrayadapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/placeholder"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="@color/listitemcolor"
android:padding="10dip">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/locationitem_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/like"
                android:textColor="#008000"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Likes"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:textColor="#008000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:id="@+id/number_of_likes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="15"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dislike"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dislikes"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:id="@+id/number_of_dislikes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code for arrayadapter:

```
 public class LocationItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LocationItem> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<LocationItem> items;

public LocationItemAdapter(Context context,
        List<LocationItem> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.locationitem_listview_element, objects);

    this.context = context;
    items = (ArrayList<LocationItem>) objects;

}





/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    View rowview = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.locationitem_listview_element, null);

    }
    else
    {
        rowview = convertView;
    }

    ((TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.locationitem_name)).setText(items.get(position).getName());
    ((TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.number_of_likes)).setText(String.valueOf(items.get(position).getLikes()));
    ((TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.number_of_dislikes)).setText(String.valueOf(items.get(position).getDislikes()));
    LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    //TextView tv = (TextView)inflater1.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
    tv.setText("My name is blah");
    tv.setTextColor(R.color.black);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    //tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)rowview.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
    //((LinearLayout)rowview.findViewById(R.id.placeholder)).addView(tv);
    ll.addView(tv);
    rowview.setTag(items.get(position));
    return rowview;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct to me.  Perhaps the embed is successful but ll takes up no space on the screen?  Can you verify that placeholder takes up some amount of visible space on the screen by setting it's background color to hot pink or something?

Comment: i have added another linearlayout as a direct child to the placeholder(linearlayout). and i have given it layout weight of "0.3"and then added the textview to it, but still its not showing up :(:(

Comment: i think the problem is in your layout xml.  not sure yet what exactly the problem is though.

Comment: i have checked in hierarchyviewer tool also..the textview is not there also.so i guess the embed itself didnt happen. but why ?

Comment: This is a longshot but try adding rowview.invalidate right before you return rowview.

Comment: Also, given that the added item's dimensions are set to match the parent, I think that once it starts working it will obscure everything else.

Comment: earlier i have put those added item's dimensions to wrapcontent..but i have changed them to matchparent just to experiment. and by the way rowview.invalidate isnt working..i have checked in hierarchyviewer also, but i couldnt find the textview embedded...:(:(